How to make a realistic pancake movement with unity physics engine
I am making a VR simulator where you can make pancakes, while my goal is to learn how to work with the physics engine. The challenge that I cannot figure out yet is how to make the pancake realistically move on the pan and sliding around the edges or be prepared for a flip etc.
So far, I used a joint to connect the pan to the right controller and used capsule colliders for the pan's edges and a box collider for the bottom. On the pancake, there is a cylinder with a mesh collider on it to make the collider flat. The flipping needs to be adjusted through the rigidbody values (but any other suggestions are welcome), however I am having trouble making the pancake sliding around the edges.
The solution that I have found so far is to use cloth, but after taking time to understand how cloth works, I have been trying my best to apply it but either I am missing something or there is another way to do it, so please let me know how you would solve this issue or where my mistake is
Video: https://imgur.com/a/fl3T0Ub



